# How can I solve this Martingale Problem with fractions

Tags: markov-chains, martingales, polya-urn-model

I am working on an exercise from previous years in my university that states that :

In a village there are living N people and they decide with an interesting way about some actions. Specifically, if someone proposes an action, then all the N villagers vote for it with YES or NO. The next day each villager re-adjusts her/his opinion independently from the other villagers, and votes again with probability equal to the probability of the total (maximum) supporters of the previous day.This voting process continues until all N agree on the same opinion.

**1)**

If $Y_{n}$ is the total number of YES voters the day $n$ , describe the transition probabilities of the chain $\{Y_{n} :n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}\}$

**2)**

Prove that the percentage of $\Pi_{n}$ supporters of YES the day $n$ defines a martingale.

**My though: **

I think that is like a polya-urn like problem that has $i$ YES voters and $j$ NO voters.

So the transition probabilities are:

$p(x,y)=P[Y_{n+1}=Y|X_{n}=x] = \begin{cases} \frac{j+k}{i+j+k} &\text{with probability} :  \frac{j}{N}   \\
\frac{j}{i+j+k} &\text{with probability} :  \frac{i}{N}
\end{cases}$

The second question I don't know it.If someone can help me with it, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your notation for the transition probabilities is a little off.  You have an $X_n$ process that isn't defined anywhere, and have $i$ and $j$ running around that don't appear in $p(x,y)$ anywhere.

If I interpret the question statement correctly, then given $Y_n = i$, $Y_{n+1}$ is binomially distributed with parameter $\frac yN$.  This implies $$\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1} = j | Y_n = i) = \binom{j}{N} \left(\frac iN\right)^j \left(\frac{N-i}{N}\right)^{N-j}.$$

To show $\Pi_n$ is a martingale, we can just use that given $Y_n$, $Y_{n+1}$ is binomially distributed with parameter $\frac{Y_n}{N}$ to conclude $\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}|Y_n] = Y_n$.  Hence $$\mathbb{E}[\Pi_{n+1}|\Pi_n] = \mathbb{E}\left[\left.\frac{Y_{n+1}}{N}\right|\Pi_n\right] = \frac{Y_n}{N} = \Pi_n.$$

Comment: Thanks you very much.I though it was polya-urn. Now if I want to calculate the $E[(\Pi_{n+1} -\Pi_{n})^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]$ ?

Comment: You can rewrite it as $\frac{1}{N^2}\mathbb{E}[(Y_{n+1}-Y_n)^2|\mathcal F_n]$ and the formula for the variance of the binomial distribution to evaluate it as $\frac{1}{N^2}Y_n (1-\frac{Y_n}{N}) = \frac 1N \Pi_n(1-\Pi_n)$.

Comment: i am obliged.Clear answer.

Comment: can you explain me with calculations how you found that $$\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1} = j | Y_n = i) = \binom{j}{N} \left(\frac iN\right)^j \left(\frac{N-i}{N}\right)^{N-j}.$$ please edit it step by step the calculations in order to better understand it.

Comment: That's just the definition of the binomial distribution - no calculations necessary.

Comment: I don't follow.You say that $Y_n$ is binomially distributed with parameter $y/N$.So I understand that $Y_n \sim B(N,y/N)={i\choose y/N}p^{y/N}(1-p)^{I-y/N}$?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo.  If $Y_n = i$ then $Y_{n+1}$ is binomially distributed with parameter $p=\frac iN$.  That means the probability $Y_{n+1} = j$ is the expression given in the answer.

Comment: Therefore is : ${N\choose j} {i\choose N}^j (1-\frac{i}{N})^{N-j}$ not  ${j\choose N}$